# Stuck on a Probability Question

Tags: probability

Hi I am stuck on this probability question and don't know what to do.

Q. A survey is carried out on a computer network. The probability that a log on to the network is successful is 0.92. Find the probability that exactly five out of nine users that attempt to log on will do so successfully.

Comment: What do you know of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of an event $A$ happening excactly $k$ times using the Fundamental Principle of Multiplication in couting is:

$$
P = P(A)^k
$$

But this event happens out of $n$ tries, so we must also add the probability of not getting the event which is :$1-P(A)$, and the latter happens $n-k$ times and using the same principle we get:

$$
P' = {(1-P(A))}^{(n-k)}
$$

Now to get the total probability we apply the same principle for the two to get:

$$
p = {(1-P(A))}^{(n-k)}P(A)^k
$$

But this can happen in different arrangement or in a different order and so we must include them too, all we have to do now is multiply our probability by the number of times it can occur, which is:

$$
n = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$

We finally get:

$$
P = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}{(1-P(A))}^{(n-k)}P(A)^k
$$

Can you apply the same technique for this problem?

Notes:

Refer to my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387150/if-team-a-wins-in-a-single-game-against-team-b-1-3-of-the-time-whats-the-proba/1387158#1387158) to get a deeper explanation

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it. What is n,k,a?

Comment: $n$ is the number of tries, $k$ is the number of times the event $A$ happens. $A$ is just an event not a number

Comment: Still having trouble with it. Can you fill in the first line of the sum so I can see what you mean.

Comment: @Tom the number of tries in your question is $n=9$, and the number of times your event gets realized is $k=5$, now you gave the probability to be $0.92$, so $P(A) = 0.92$, now all you have to do is plug in the values

Comment: Ok I actually had all of that but I get an answer of 340.10 which I don't think is right. This is what is get I must be multiplying the powers wrong or something.  126(0.08)^4 (0.92)^5

Comment: @Tom you made a mistake in calculation you should get $P = 0.00340$

Comment: Ok just after calculating that again and got that answer right thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help ^^